# Unable to load bzip2 in native library of Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, bzip2

My environment is
CentOS 7;
Spark 1.6.1;
Hadoop 2.6.4; and I have two slave-node in a cluster mode.

When I tried hadoop command, I got `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform… using builtin-java classes where applicable`

And I check `hadoop checknative -a`, I got all false responses. Part of this problem is solved when I add

```
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native/"
```

in `hadoop-env.sh` and reinstall openssl-devel.
However, I still got warning when I type `hadoop checknative -a`:

```
[hadoop@host-10-174-101-17 ~]$ hadoop checknative -a
16/07/13 14:36:24 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
16/07/13 14:36:24 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
zlib:    true /lib64/libz.so.1
snappy:  true /lib64/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:     true revision:99
bzip2:   false 
openssl: true /lib64/libcrypto.so
16/07/13 14:36:24 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

I reinstalled bizp2 and I check `bzip2 --version`:

```
[hadoop@host-10-174-101-17 ~]$ bzip2 --version
bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.

   Copyright (C) 1996-2010 by Julian Seward.

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms set out in the LICENSE file, which is included
   in the bzip2-1.0.6 source distribution.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   LICENSE file for more details.

bzip2: I won't write compressed data to a terminal.
bzip2: For help, type: `bzip2 --help'.
```

What's more, I check dictionary ~/lib64/, both `libbz2.so.1` and `libbz2.so` exist, it's said that if bzip2 is well loaded, this should be the path.
It seems that bzip2 is well installed, but hadoop cannot load it.
I also tried to recompile as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10409 mentioned.
If I follow exactly as it, it doesn't work:

```
[hadoop@host-10-174-101-17 ~]$ strings /export/apps/hadoop/latest/lib/native/libhadoop.so | grep initIDs
strings: '/export/apps/hadoop/latest/lib/native/libhadoop.so': No such file
```

If I change path to my path of hadoop: /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so, this is what it got:

```
[hadoop@host-10-174-101-17 ~]$ strings /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so | grep initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_lz4_Lz4Compressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_lz4_Lz4Decompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_snappy_SnappyCompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_snappy_SnappyDecompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_crypto_OpensslCipher_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib_ZlibCompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib_ZlibDecompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_lz4_Lz4Compressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_lz4_Lz4Decompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_snappy_SnappyCompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_snappy_SnappyDecompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_crypto_OpensslCipher_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib_ZlibCompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib_ZlibDecompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_lz4_Lz4Decompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_lz4_Lz4Compressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib_ZlibDecompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_snappy_SnappyCompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_snappy_SnappyDecompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_io_compress_zlib_ZlibCompressor_initIDs
Java_org_apache_hadoop_crypto_OpensslCipher_initIDs
```

Though, I check `hadoop checknative -a`, still it doesn't work.
What can I do in this situation? Thank you very much.

Comment: Might this answer be of help?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/469528/install-native-bzip2-on-ubuntu-14-04